# Can (aggregate) functions be used to define a column?

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns, postgresql-9.6

Assume a table like this one:

```
a | b | total
--|---|------
1 | 2 |  3
4 | 7 | 11
…

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE summedup (
    a double precision DEFAULT 0
  , b double precision DEFAULT 0
  --, total double precision
);
INSERT INTO summedup (a, b) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO summedup (a, b) VALUES (4, 7);

SELECT a, b, a + b as total FROM summedup;
```

It's easy to sum up the first two columns on SELECT.

But does Postgres (9.6) also support the ability to define `total` as the sum of the other two columns? If so:

- What is the syntax?
- What is this type of operation called (*aggregates* typically sum up cells over multiple rows, not columns.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is typically called a "computed column".

Postgres 9.6 does not support that (Postgres 12 - to be released in Q4 2019 - [will](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/ddl-generated-columns.html)).

But for such a simple sum, I wouldn't bother storing redundant information.

If you don't want to repeat the expression, create a view.

Comment: "storing redundant information" would I guess assume that the computed column in the forthcoming release of Postgres would not be virtual (which it can be, e.g. in MySQL) +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: both. You can define it as "virtual" or "stored".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a View.

```sql
CREATE VIEW table_with_sum AS 
 SELECT id, a, b, a + b as total FROM summedup;
```

then you can query the view for the sum.

```
SELECT total FROM table_with_sum where id=5;
```

The View does not store the sum for each row, the `total`column is computed every time you query the View. If your goal is to make your query more efficient, this will not help.

There is an other way: add the column to the table and create triggers for update and insert that update the `total` column every time a row is modified.